# Audio/Voice over webRTC

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc

I am trying to implement a one directional voice transmission with `webRTC` and php as a server side.

Looking at the [samples](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/audio), I fail to understand the `webRTC` mechanism.

The way I see it, the flow should look like this:

1. Caller and recipient register on server
2. Recipient listens for incoming calls
3. Caller asks server for recipient's IP
4. Server sends IP to caller
5. Caller connects to recipient directly

However the [sample code](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/audio), (that runs on a local machine)

```
function call() {
  trace('Starting call');
  var servers = null;
  var pcConstraints = {
    'optional': []
  };
  pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, pcConstraints);
  trace('Created local peer connection object pc1');
  pc1.onicecandidate = iceCallback1;
  pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, pcConstraints);
  trace('Created remote peer connection object pc2');
  pc2.onicecandidate = iceCallback2;
  pc2.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
  trace('Requesting local stream');
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false
  })
  .then(gotStream)
  .catch(function(e) {
    alert('getUserMedia() error: ' + e.name);
  });
}
```

Does not use ip address or any kind of identification token that could be translated into `IP`.

How could that be ?

Comment: https://github.com/webrtc/samples

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get started you will need to provide some kind of signaling channel between your clients. Most people are using some protocol (typically JSON based or SIP) over WebSockets to something like Node.js, SIP server or message broker on the backend which can then bridge between the two clients. You can pretty much send blobs of data that are pulled directly from the WebRTC PeerConnection. This includes SDPs, ICE candidates, etc. The PeerConnection can directly consume the data generated from the other peer so you don't have to deal with formatting the data. Just pack it into a JSON object and send it to Node over a WebSockets and let Node send it out to the other side. Its up to you to design how registered endpoints find each other and create this bridge.

We used MQTT over WebSockets to do this. In our model each client subscribes on their own MQTT topic and each side can publish messages to the other client on those topics. Clients register these topics with a back end service that is subscribed on a topic as well or you can use retained messages to let the MQTT broker manage the topics. You can read more about our approach here: http://www.wasdev.net/webrtc. We open sourced the signaling protocol and you can use any open MQTT broker for this. We also created SDKs including an AngularJS module you can play with here: http://angular-rtcomm.wasdev.developer.ibm.com/

Comment: Upvote for first paragraph. Good summary of basics of signaling.